# Looping through a list of interactive questions

Tags: java, android

I have a list of questions to asked, and then depending on some flags in the question object we have to specify the possible options of the answers.

The question here is about how to loop through them and wait for the next button click to show the next question?

I tried:

```java
for (Question q : questionsList) {
    boolean bringNext = false;
    while(!bringNext){
        // Design the layout
        Button next = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Save user answer
                bringNext = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then put this in `onCreate`, but I don't think this is the best approach.

Any Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create multiple buttons inside loop. Just create one button and use index variable to get next question when button clicked. 
Here is sample code

```
int currentQueIndex=0; //member variable

next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if(currentQueIndex<questionsList.size()){
              Question q:questionsList.get(currentQueIndex);//use q to render your layout
              currentQueIndex++;
           }
        }
    });
```